# Would it make sense to provide more targeted SO careers ads, e.g give the users some power over what they see?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs, advertising

For instance, if I were to jump the ship, I have certain geographical areas in mind. Also, while the tags of the question that I am viewing should help, there are jobs in certain languages that I would almost certainly never undertake.

I think Facebook has a way of collecting feedback from users about what kind of ads they do and do not want to see.

I do not mind targeted ads, as long as they are truly targeted. It would be nice if SO was acting as my passive job hunter; I just want a smarter, more personal hunter - something that can do a bit more than just keyword matching.

Comment: Given how few adverts there are for UK jobs, I don't see a need to target more the on the country someone is in for none USA

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Comment: LOL, and in the rare case where finally "No longer can be reproduced" close reason **should** be used...... it's not. Changes to the system (aborting Jobs) render the question obsolete, it **is** about Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 4):

We've been discussing many different ways of making results more relevant (both the listings that are shown to you on the careers site as the ads we show on stackoverflow.com).

In no particular order (and with no promise whatsoever wrt if and when these might be implemented :) ):

- Use tags user is active in to determine what listings to show
- Allow user to save searches and mark one as default
- Allow users to actually rate ads Hulu style
- Try to match jobs against the user's CV
- Geo-target not only on current location, but on locations indicated in CV
- Probably some other ways that I can't quite recall right now

I can't promise all of these will make it in, or to what extend, but we will make the ads we show you more and more relevant. As you say in your comment to Kop's answer, it makes good sense to align supply with demand.

Answer (score 0):

Except that careers usually works the reverse; the company finds you.

Yes, there are traditional listings, but I believe that for each listing there are several searches by companies, since the very careers system discourages listings.

Comment: I do not fully understand this, sorry. Could you elaborate? Also, unless advertising on S.O. is extremely cheap, why would a company seeking a Perl hacker want to try to impress those who abhor Perl? Perhaps it is a small market ... well it can't be monster.com was quite well off at some point.